# Suggestion for "high-level-assembly" tag

Tags: feature-request

High level assembly (HLA) is an assembly language aimed at allowing you to learn assembly without having to write pure assembly. However, since it's a bit obscure, setting it up can be kind of a pain, and lots of things can go wrong in the installation process, so I believe it deserves it's own tag. I recently made a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469433/using-high-level-assembly-hla-sh-1-hlaparse-not-found/1469434?noredirect=1#comment2575372_1469434) about it but didn't have the appropriate tag.

Comment: Why do you think we need this tag? So far we have one question regarding this topic, so it doesn't seem like a very popular topic with the need for a tag.

Comment: My suspicion is that you might have a better chance with such questions on SO where there is some HLA action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hla

Answer (score 3):

In cases like these we usually wait to create a new tag until the topic has more traction on this site. Currently there is only one question about HLA at Ask Ubuntu. By contrast there are 75 questions tagged with [hla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hla) at Stack Overflow.

I've created several new tags at Ask Ubuntu over the years, many of which had more than 100 questions containing the tag's keyword at the time the tag was created. I also created a tag extract and a tag wiki for each new tag and tagged at least ten questions containing the tag's keyword (preferably in the question's title) with the new tag in order to make the tag easy to understand and hard to delete.